# MySQL Restart Failed in MySQL 8.0.30

Tags: mysql, database, restart, systemctl

While Restarting the MySQL server version 8.0.30 it is getting failed and couldn't able to fix the issue till now.

```
 ESCOD
● mysqld.service - MySQL Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2022-12-31 08:37:07 GMT; 1h 7min ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
  Process: 631823 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 631795 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysqld_pre_systemd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 631823 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "Server shutdown complete"

Dec 31 08:37:06 fcg-db-mysql-oracle-lx-129.142 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Server...
Dec 31 08:37:07 fcg-db-mysql-oracle-lx-129.142 mysqld[631823]: 2022-12-31T08:37:07.614931Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30) starting as process 631823
Dec 31 08:37:07 fcg-db-mysql-oracle-lx-129.142 mysqld[631823]: 2022-12-31T08:37:07.614964Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010338] [Server] Can't find error-message file '/usr/share/mysql-8.0/errmsg.sys'. Check error-message file location and 'lc-messages-dir' configuration directive.
Dec 31 08:37:07 fcg-db-mysql-oracle-lx-129.142 mysqld[631823]: 2022-12-31T08:37:07.620958Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011011] [Server] Failed to find valid data directory.
Dec 31 08:37:07 fcg-db-mysql-oracle-lx-129.142 mysqld[631823]: 2022-12-31T08:37:07.621191Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
Dec 31 08:37:07 fcg-db-mysql-oracle-lx-129.142 mysqld[631823]: 2022-12-31T08:37:07.621215Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
Dec 31 08:37:07 fcg-db-mysql-oracle-lx-129.142 mysqld[631823]: 2022-12-31T08:37:07.621569Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
Dec 31 08:37:07 fcg-db-mysql-oracle-lx-129.142 systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 31 08:37:07 fcg-db-mysql-oracle-lx-129.142 systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 31 08:37:07 fcg-db-mysql-oracle-lx-129.142 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server.
~
```

while from suggestions from some blogs i have tried mysqld --initialize --console, but it is also throwing error like below

```
mysqld: Can't create directory '/var/lib/mysql/' (OS errno 17 - File exists)
2022-12-31T18:12:49.257034Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30) initializing of server in progress as process 3353
2022-12-31T18:12:49.257062Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010339] [Server] Using pre 5.5 semantics to load error messages from /usr/share/mysql-8.0/. If this is not intended, refer to the documentation for valid usage of --lc-messages-dir and --language parameters.
2022-12-31T18:12:49.257067Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010342] [Server] Can't read from messagefile '/usr/share/mysql-8.0/errmsg.sys'
2022-12-31T18:12:49.257809Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
2022-12-31T18:12:49.257841Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-12-31T18:12:49.257943Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
[fcgredim@fcg-db-mysql-oracle-lx-129 ~]$
```

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0):

1 . Run the below command to see if there are any errors in the file configuration.

```
mysqld --validate-config
```

> Can't create directory '/var/lib/mysql/' (OS errno 17 - File exists)

2 . The above error indicates that something wrong with `/var/lib/mysql/`. Check if this path exists, and it has this permission `drwx------ mysql mysql`. (Also, if `SElinx` installed, check if it has the right `label`)

Comment: as you said i have run the command i got the below one, any suggestion

[fcgredim@fcg-db-mysql-oracle-lx-129 ~]$ mysqld --validate-config

2023-01-01T02:33:10.591059Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010342] [Server] Can't read from messagefile '/usr/share/mysql-8.0/errmsg.sys'

Comment: Please check this [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/102909/898329), I think it solves the same problem as yours.